# 403 when calling the object from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops

I have two aws accounts. I wanted to upload the objects from Account A to the S3 bucket residing in Account B. Also Account B should be able to access these objects.

1. I have created an S3 bucket and gave the below policy

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "Policy1533932697318",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt1533932695665",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:root” 
               },
               "Action": "s3:*",
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. The account I gave in the Principal is Account A. As expected I could able to write and read the data from Account A.
3. But I am getting "fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden" error **when I am trying to read the data from Account B which bucket resides.**
4. I also tried adding my Account B root account in policy principal JSON is complaining about the syntax.

Please let me know is there any solution for this issue.

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "Policy1533932697318",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Stmt1533932695665",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:root”
                           "arn:aws:iam::987654321321:root”
                },
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my bucket_policy.json

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: solved the above problem. The issue was the owner of the object who is uploading to the bucket. I had to add --acl "bucket-owner-full-control" while uploading the object to s3